# encoding of =1 in emails

Tags: php, encoding, email

I have probably a stupid problem. In a script I generate a URL with GET parameters, something like 'www.mydomain.com/index.php?item=1234'. This URL will be sent by PHP through mail() in an UTF-8 encoding (the scriptfile itself also is utf-8). Now each time I have the GET-Parameter with two numbers after the '=' the URL in the email looks like 'www.mydomain.com/index.php?item□34' with a rectangle instead of '=12'. I am sure there is an easy way to fix this?

Thanks in advance,

Maenny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding in which encoding sequences start with `=`. Instead of struggling with encoding manually, choose a mail library which does that (and a lot more) for you. I recommend [PHPmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

Also, url parameters are ugly. It is very easy to set nice urls via the Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module and use urls like `www.mydomain.com/item/1234`, which has the added benefit of being implementation-independent and somewhat more SEO-friendly. (For full SEO-friendliness use `www.mydomain.com/item/my-cool-item` or at least `www.mydomain.com/item/1234/my-cool-item`.)

Comment: The minimalistic solution, which I would strongly recommend against, is replacing `=` with `=3D`.

Comment: Thx I found this:

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.quoted-printable-encode.php

and added the function to my includes.